# How to hide the view button which is on the right top position in scheduler in Kendo UI ?I set the view is MonthView and I have only one view

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I set the view is  MonthView and I have only one view,so I do not want to show the  view button which is on the right top position.Does scheduler has the property to hide the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to find the class of the button,and then hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to just use the month view. Then if you don't want to see the button you would have to find the class of the button and set it to display:none.

```
views: [{ type: "month", selected: true }],
```